# How can I get the height and width of a CustomImageField item in Sitecore?

Tags: image, height, sitecore, width, media

I've been searching for solutions but everything I've found has referenced `ImageField` items rather than `CustomImageField`, and the solutions don't work. This is my Image object:

```cs
public CustomImageField Image
{
    get
    {
        return new CustomImageField(InnerItem, InnerItem.Fields["Image"]);
    }
}
```

`Image` has `Image.MediaItem` and `Image.MediaUrl`. `Image.MediaItem` has a `Size` property, but does not have `Height` and `Width`. How do I get the height and width of the image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using some custom `CustomImageField` class and without the code of that class, we cannot guarantee that any solution will work. But:

Assuming that `Image.MediaItem` is of `Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem` type you can try to get inner item and `Width` and `Height` fields of it:

```cs
Image.MediaItem.InnerItem["Width"]
Image.MediaItem.InnerItem["Height"]
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to use this to capture the height and width when casting an image item to a Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem in Sitecore Powershell and wanting to get the dimensions. This alluded me until I read your answer!

For those interested, here is the relevant Powershell script code:  
`$mediaItem = New-Object Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem($item)`
`width = $mediaItem.InnerItem["Width"]`  
`height = $mediaItem.InnerItem["height"]`